# React app cannot compile if component has IIFE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Below is my component code.

```js
function App() {
  !function() {
    console.log("foo")
  }()

  return (
    <div>APP</div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I got a compile error when building.

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

src\App.js
  Line 2:3:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I don't understand why I get a compile error.
This is valid JavaScript code.

Can I ignore this error?

---

Actually, I use it to use async function in useEffect.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    !async function() {
        await something()
    }()
})
```

Comment: what is `!function`?

Comment: That's a _linting_ error, https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions. In this case your IIFE is pointless anyway.

Comment: I would even ask: what are you trying to achieve by calling the function like this

Comment: @AlexShtromberg variable scoping maybe?

Comment: @andymccullough something like `function scopingVariables(){}; scopingVariables();` ?

Comment: @AlexShtromberg like `function (){ const x = y;}` where `x` is scoped only to that function.

Comment: @blz try - `useEffect(() => { (async function(){ await something(); })()})`, still not sure what the `!` is for?

Comment: @andymccullough It is to create an IIFE. Normally you'd use braces: `(()=>{})()` but that is not the ONLY way to create an IIFE. All an IIFE is is a function EXPRESSION (the **E** in IIFE) that is immediately called. You can create expressions by using `()` or by any math operators like `!` or `+` or `-` etc. or by putting your function on the right of an `=` sign eg: `_ = ()=>{}()` etc.

Comment: As far as I know, there are two patterns of IIFE.
`(function(){})()` and `!function(){}()`.
I prefer the latter because the latter is easier to write than the former.
`!` is unary operator, sometimes `~` is also used.

I am using default config of CRA. Why this rule is set as default?

Comment: IIFE of `(function(){})()` works. Thank you.

Comment: @blz There are more than two. You can also do `-function(){}()` or `tmp=function(){}()` or `0*function(){}()` etc however you should only use `(function(){}())` or `(function(){})()` as those are the only ones most javascript developers are familiar with. The others just cause confusion as shown by the comments you are getting

Answer (score 0):

can you try this.

```
function App() {
  true && function() {
    console.log("foo")
  }()
 return !function(){console.log("poo")}
  return (
    <div>APP</div>
  )
}
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20171201033208/http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/#iife

Answer (score 0):

The unary operator IIFE works well with no-semi styles, so I finally solved it by changing the eslintConfig.

```
"rules": {
  "no-unused-expressions": "off"
}
```